# Why is the program not accepting my code when it returns the same answer?

Tags: python, json

I have homework problem and I wrote the code and every time I submit it, it says that the returned answer and expected answer are the same but it's still marked as wrong.
Here is the question

Write a function named "json_average" that takes a JSON formatted string as a parameter in the format of an array of objects where each object has keys "mass", "density", "temperature", and "velocity" and each key maps to a floating point number. This function should return the average "mass" of all the objects in the array as a JSON string in the format {"mass": }

I tried writing the code a few different ways and I still get the same result. Here is my most recent attempt.

```
import json 
def json_average (x):
    data = json.loads(x)
    summ = 0 
    n = 0
    for s in data:
        a = s["mass"]
        summ = summ + a
        n  = n + 1
    d = {"mass" : (summ/n)}
    return(d)
```

Here is what it returns

```
    input ['[{"mass": 43.56, "density": 251.94, "velocity": 60.65, "temperature": 15.06}, {"mass": 7.36, "density": 856.29, "velocity": 84.25, "temperature": 26.59}, {"mass": 95.26, "density": 360.24, "velocity": 67.77, "temperature": 0.25}, {"mass": 82.25, "density": 402.19, "velocity": 82.79, "temperature": -4.6}]']

returned: {'mass': 57.1075}
expected: {"mass": 57.1075}
```

Comment: You are returning `d` which is a dictionary object, but the question asks you to return a JSON string.

Comment: According to the assignment you should return a JSON string, i.e. `return json.dumps(d)`

Comment: @kaya3 thank you so much! I guess I read the question wrong. I returned json.dumps(d) and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in your function:

```py
d = json.dumps(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

- As already noted, you're most likely missing `json.dumps(d)`

#### Other items to note:

- It's not a good idea to have your variable names mirror built-in python functions or data types (e.g. `summ`, mirrors `sum`)
- Variable names should be descriptive: `summ` → `mass_sum`
- `n  = n + 1` → `n += 1`
- There's no need to keep track of the number of values with `n`, unless you're not allowed to use [built-in functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html). Use `enumerate`, like `for i, s in enumerate(data):`.
- For learning purposes, here are a couple of alternative implementations of your code.

### Alternate code:

```py
def json_average(x):
    data = json.loads(x)
    mass_sum = 0 
    for i, s in enumerate(data, 1):
        mass_sum += s['mass']
    return json.dumps({'mass': mass_sum/i})
```

### Use [`list comprehension`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

- A list comprehension is a pythonic `for-loop`
- Use `sum` and `len` on `mass_values`

```py
def json_average(x):
    data = json.loads(x)
    mass_values = [value['mass'] for value in data]
    return json.dumps({'mass': sum(mass_values)/len(mass_values)})
```

Comment: Thanks and I just wrote summ to keep track,  I changed it to s in my code which made it easier.